# Using jQuery function in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 3 PHP files named as,

1. index page
2. books
3. user

**Index Page**

```
<link href="colorbox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function bookRetr(str)
{
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("more-info").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("more-info").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","showbook.php?id="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
    $(".popup").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:750, innerHeight:520});
});
</script>

<div id='$bookid' onClick="bookRetr(this.id)></div>
<div id='more-info'></div>
```

**bookshow.php**

```
$bookid = $_GET['id'];
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookdatabase WHERE ID='{$bookid}'");
$fetch  = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$user   = $fetch['userID'];

echo "<a href='showuser?id=$user' class='popup'>My name is X</a>";
```

The book show echo part is shown in my index page when i click on the div, but when click on My name is X, it open a new page but its actually supposed to open a popup. I got the popup named as colorbox plugin.

I'm unable to figure out where exactly i'm going wrong that the popup never opens.

Comment: sorry for writing the wrong php file name, just to correct the post, its showbook.php, so that its not confusing to answer.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are [in the deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary But that is not where i get the error, the error is the popup never opens. All I want to do is to pop the popup on my screen, thanks for the info.

Comment: I realize that. I am encouraging you to [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Thank you sir, I really appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$(".popup").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:750, innerHeight:520});
```

Try:

```
$('.popup').live('click', function() {
  $.colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'), open:true, iframe:true, innerWidth:750, innerHeight:520});
  return false;
});
```

OR if it won't work:

```
$("body").on("click", ".popup", function() {
  $.fn.colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'), open:true, iframe:true, innerWidth:750, innerHeight:520});
  return false;
});
```

Hope it helps a little

Comment: how can i set the inner width and height?

Comment: When I click once this code works, when i click second time it does'nt work.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you are dynamically generating the link, You will have to use jquery live to make it work. Here is the code

```
  $(function(){
                //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
                $(".popup").live("click",function(){
                    $.colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:750, innerHeight:520});
                    return false;
                });

            });
```

Dins

Comment: This code does'nt work, its shows a popup for just a second and then opens a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to hijack the natural execution of clicking a href link...you need to add return false , which will essentially tell the browser to not treat your href like a link

If you change your popup function like this it should work, course readd your colorbox opts after the href opt by comma separation like so

```
 $('.popup').click(function(){
   $.colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'), iframe:true, innerWidth:750, innerHeight:520});
   return false;
  });
```

Added your opts and code cleanup